# Magnific Popup link format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So.... This is my problem. It seemed that magnific popup wouldn't work but my libraries were added correctly and my console didn't display any errors. So I figured it out by removing some tags in my link.
I have this html markup that is not working:

```
<a class="image-link" href="img/gallery1.jpg"> 
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery1.jpg" alt="">
  <span class="zoom"></span>
</a>
```

Here's my simple script for the lightbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
  });
</script>
```

But if I remove the span, the lightbox triggers correctly. I have that span because it is an icon with some hover effects in css. I'd like to make this plugin work with it. Please help me and don't assume too much. I don't know about javascript/jquery programming.

Comment: Do u require all need libraries? jquery, magnific.js, magnific.css ?

Comment: can't you use `:after` selector to apply the effects you're doing on the `<span>` and remove that span?

Comment: Fabio do you mean add the styles to .img-responsive:after? or where should I add them? *blushes*

Comment: @CynthiaLara that's the idea, but since you're probably using `.img-responsive` in other places where you don't want that effect probably `.image-link > .img-responsive:after{/*your styles*/}`

Comment: It won't work as I want it because I need an icon image to appear on hover as an overlay. I tested it and no luck..

Comment: can you post your styles for that?

Comment: Sorry was out of the office. This is the css styles: .zoom { 
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: url(../img/zoom.png) no-repeat center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }